# How can I calculate the requirements of a fan to obtain a defined airflow after a HEPA filter?

Tags: airflow, air, air-quality

I would like to understand how can I calculate the requirements of a fan in the following scenario.

I want to obtain some airflow (m^3/h or CFM)after a HEPA filter. I have found some specification sheets of a HEPA filter and they offer some parameters like for certain dimensions a pressure drop at certain airflow. [For example.](https://www.airclean.co.uk/download/4724%5D)

Then I have looked at many fan specs and what is almost always available are dimensions, RPM, airflow and maximal pressure (or a curve of their relation).

I would like to calculate which minimum requirements should I expect from the fan to work in this really simplified example.

I made a paint sketch to illustrate the problem.
[image: expected airflow after filter]

Given a fixed box that contains both, a fixed HEPA filter, how can I calculate the required fan to obtain an expected airflow after the filter?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you have determined a required air flow rate, but that would normally be the starting point.  You need a particular flow rate to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.  Then you would select a filter rated for that flow rate.  The dimensions of the filter are determined by the manufacturer based on the flow rate.  The filter specs will also tell you the pressure drop through the filter.  You now have to add any other pressure drop in the system, such as ducting on the inlet and/or outlet sides of the fan/filter.  It's common to add a little margin to both flow rate and pressure to make sure the system will still work as the filter begins to plug.  Now you pick a fan that will provide the required flow and pressure.

Comment: Hello, yes, the required air flow outside the filter (Q) is known, for example 400CFM, and the dimensions of the filter too.